# Build Telegram-Sdk for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Telegram-iOS-SDK/0.0.1/

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

```
platform :ios, ‘8.0’
use_frameworks!

target 'BALKISFS' do

    pod 'Telegram-iOS-SDK'

end
```

Not able to install cocoa pods for Telegram SDK.

Answer (score 0):

As per github Link

That repository is removed from github

**Error :**

> remote: Repository not found. fatal: repository
>   'https://github.com/batkov/Telegram-iOS-SDK.git/' not found

So for that you need to contact API author

```
Author
Hariton Batkov, batkov@i.ua
```

Hope this will helps.